# Implementing different endpoints in same rest api class

Tags: apex, webservices, apexrest

I'm trying to implement a web service in apex.

I have two GET methods

1. `GET /application`
2. `GET /application/status`

1 had been already implemented in the following way. I am given the task to implement 2. Should I insert the logic in the same method below or is there a way to define a new method based on the endpoint?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/application/*')
global with sharing class ApplicationAPI {
    @HttpGet
    global static void get() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        try {
            String appID = RestUtil.getPathParam(req, 'application/');
            if(appID == null) {
                //get multiple apps
            } else {
                //get one app
            }
        } 
        catch(BadRequestException e) {
            res.statusCode = e.getStatusCode();
            RestUtil.setResErrorBody(res, e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a new class and map it as:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/application/status')
```

Because of the matching rules, `/application/status` will map to this new class, while `/application/anythingElse` will map to `/application/*`. Note that you *could* choose to parse the RestContext.request.requestUri and make a call to one or more methods based on that, but that's probably overkill in your case.

In that case, you might do something like:

```
if(RestContext.request.requestUri.endsWith('/status')) {
  return getSystemStatus();
} else {
  return doApplicationLogic();
}
```

(Whatever that means for the context of your application).

Comment: Looks to me like the intent is to parse the URI; IMHO that would be the cleaner way to go here too.